# no se visualiza archivo PDF en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, objeto, iframe

espero alguien pueda orientarme al respecto.
Tengo una aplicacion mobil en la cual tengo que mostrar un pdf, si abro el index desde un explorador, todo funciona correctamente pero si compilo la aplicacion, este no se muestra.
Lo estoy llamando con un **embeded**, ya lo intente tambien con un **object** y con un **iframe**.

Este es el codigo en el js con el que lo mando llamar:

```
        {
            var $newDiv = $("<div id='div-IMG' class='topcoat-overlay-bg'>"+
            "<aside class='image-overlay'>"+
                "<div style='max-width:99%; height:680px;'>"+
                    "<div id='syncStatusMsg'>" + documentDesc + "</div>"+
                         "<embed src='"+src+"' width='100%'; height='100%'>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<button class='topcoat-button--large--cta' id='closeimg'>Cerrar</button>"+
            "</aside>"+
        "</div>");
        $('body').append($newDiv);
    
        $('#closeimg').click(function()
            {
                console.log("Closing IMG");
                $('#div-IMG').remove();
             });
         
        };
```

asi se muestra en el emulador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: necesitas forzozamente que se abra dentro de tu app? no puedes hacer que una aplicación que tenga esa función lo abra?

Comment: tambien podria ser que se abra en un navegador pero no lo hace :(

Comment: intente usando inappbrowser y llamarlo de la siguiente manera , pero tampoco tuve exito .
`<window.open('"+src+"', '_blank')>`

Comment: ¿dime por favor cuál es el valor de "src" ?

Comment: el valor de src es la ruta de mi pdf, si pongo esa ruta en el navegador si lo abre, las rutas del pdf son dinamicas, por tanto son extridas d euna bd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se debe a que seguramente estas usando una ruta relativa para tu archivo .pdf, por ejemplo:

```
src="../archivospdf/archivo.pdf"
```

si defines la ruta de esta forma, cuando trates de obtenerla desde el dispositivo, tratara de buscar dentro del dispositivo el archivo.

**Lo que debes realizar para que cargue el archivo en tu dispositivo es definir la ruta absoluta de tu archivo .PDF**

```
src="https://mysite.com/archivospdf/archivo.pdf"
```

Comment: mi archivo se encuentra en una base de datos, por eos lo mando a llamar con src

Comment: Si, pero cuál es la ruta que defines en src?

Comment: el valor de src es la ruta de mi pdf, si pongo esa ruta en el navegador si lo abre, las rutas del pdf son dinamicas, por tanto son extridas d euna bd

Comment: ok, revisa lo que pongo en mi respuesta, debes definir rutas absolutas de otra forma no permitirá la carga.

Comment: existe alguna otra forma de lograrlo entonces?

Comment: con rutas relativas solo es posible si metes el archivo .PDF dentro del dispositivo.

Comment: continue con mi intento de usarlo con las rutas alternativas con window.open y mi resultado aun se muestra en blanco :(